# Change XCache settings via Puphpet

Tags: vagrant, puphpet, xcache

Can you overwrite some settings via Puphpet in /etc/php.d/xcache.ini?

Or do is there a way to create a new .ini file that overwrites the settings in xcache.ini?

This is my config.yaml for php

```
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '54'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
            - xcache
            - mbstring
            - bcmath
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
        error_reporting: 'E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE'
        auto_append_file: '0'
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_hkqo06hnuj7a:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the settings entered into each module's specific INI file via puphpet.

However, any custom INI settings you define are added into a `zzzz_custom.ini` file. Since PHP loads INI files alphabetically, this custom ini file overrides anything defined in other INI files.